# How to add links in React Array Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a React component that maps data from a .js file, containing objects in array. How can I link my title and images from within this function to access respective pages.

The title of an array of objects is 'Practices' which should open a new practices page when clicked. Within this object, there are a number of items, each of which contain an image of a practice, which when clicked must go to that specific practice page.

Here is sample code from my Practice_Data File..

```
const PRACTICES_DATA = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Practices',
      routeName: 'practices',
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Defending Centrally | Opposed Skill (12-P5)',
          imageUrl: 'https://image.mux.com/D8PU0036BeX3veIIzAKJlqiECDBoEIJak/animated.gif?width=490&height=278&fps=15',
          Theme: 12,
        },
      ]
    },

 export default PRACTICES_DATA;
```

Here is the code for my practice component:

```
import React from 'react';

import PRACTICES_DATA from './practices.data';

import CollectionPreview from '../../components/collection-preview/collection-preview';

class PracticesPage extends React.Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            collections: PRACTICES_DATA
        };
    }

    render() {
        const {collections} = this.state;
        return (
            <div className='practices-page'>
                {collections.map(({ id, ...otherCollectionProps }) => (
                    <CollectionPreview key={id} {...otherCollectionProps} />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PracticesPage;
```

There might well be an obvious answer to this, but I have been stuck on this for a while. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Yes using react router here. The Collection Preview Code is shown below:

```
import React from 'react';

import CollectionItem from '../collection-item/collection-item.component';

import './collection-preview.styles.scss';

const CollectionPreview =({ title, items }) => (
    <div className='collection-preview'>
        <h1 className='title'>{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
        <div className='preview'> 
            {items.filter((item, idx) => idx < 4)
            .map(({ id, ...otherItemProps }) => (
                <CollectionItem key={id} {...otherItemProps} />
            ))}
        </div>
    </div>
);

export default CollectionPreview;
```

Comment: What does this CollectionPreview component look like? It seems any linking that goes on would happen there. Can you share what you have so far for that?

Comment: What route management system are you using? Are you using react-router?

Comment: Sorry new to the forum, I have edited original post now to show Collection Preview Component also and yes using react router here.